# Average from multiple random networks

Tags: r, igraph

I am testing the Small World of my network by comparing it with a random one. With an igraph package I am able to generate a random network of the same parametres that I have in my original set, the same number of nodes and links. Then I calculate transitivity which in reality is also the global clustering.

What I am looking for is actually getting an average of, let's say, 1000 such calculations on 1000 newly generated random networks. How should I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem? What is the question? How to implement this, in that case, it is off-topic on this site!